# How to hide my TaskBar icon from the TaskBar at run-time?

Tags: delphi, winapi, taskbar, system-tray, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have downloaded CoolTrayIcon v.4.4.0 from:

https://torry.net/files/vcl/system/trayicons/CoolTrayIcon.zip

After installing the component in Delphi 10.4.2, in the demo folder, I have opened the project "CoolTrayTest". In this project, in a button click-handler I execute this code:

```
if IsWindowVisible(Application.Handle) then
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
```

This HIDES the TaskBar icon.

But when I try this code in my own VCL Application, the TaskBar icon is NOT hidden.

What can I do to have my own VCL Application also hide the TaskBar icon with this code? (I don't want to hide the TaskBar icon from the program start on, but deliberately with the click of a button).

**EDIT**: Following the suggestion of Remy, I use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  T: System.Win.Taskbar.TWinTaskbar;
begin
  T := System.Win.Taskbar.TWinTaskbar.Create;
  try
    if not FTaskBarButtonIsHidden then
    begin
      IsOK := T.DeleteTab(Self.Handle);
      CodeSite.Send('TForm1.btnTestClick: DeleteTab', IsOK);
      FTaskBarButtonIsHidden := IsOK;
    end
    else
    begin
      IsOK := T.AddTab(Self.Handle);
      CodeSite.Send('TForm1.btnTestClick: AddTab', IsOK);
      FTaskBarButtonIsHidden := not IsOK;
    end;
  finally
    T.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It seems to work. Does this have any side-effects?

Comment: Set MainFormOnTaskbar to false.

Comment: Delphi ships with ``TTrayIcon`` component since ages...

Comment: @DelphiCoder `TTrayIcon` is for managing System Tray notification icons. The OP is trying to manage the app's Taskbar button instead. Two different things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm aware of these two things. Just wanted to mention it for the OP, so he could get rid of an about 15 (!) years old 3rd party dependency (not updated since, there could be problems with Unicode)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `Application.ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` property is `False`, as is likely the case in the CoolTrayIcon demo, then the Taskbar button is owned by the hidden `Application` window.

When `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` is `True` instead, as is the case by default in modern Delphi projects, then the Taskbar button is owned by the `Application.MainForm` window rather than the `Application` window.

To hide/show the Taskbar button, you need to hide/show its owner window.

Alternatively, you can use the [`DeleteTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-deletetab) and [`AddTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab) methods of the Win32 [`ITaskbarList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist) Shell interface.

See the documentation about [The Taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#managing-taskbar-buttons) for more details. Particularly the sections on "Managing Taskbar Buttons" and "Modifying the Contents of the Taskbar".

Comment: Thank you for the information! When I put `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False;` in the main form's `OnCreate` event-handler then I get **TWO** (!) icons on the TaskBar! How can I avoid this?

Comment: Now I have solved the problem with the two icons by instead of doing it in the form's `OnCreate` event-handler, I changed `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;` to `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;` in the DPR file. Are there any side-effects of doing this?

Comment: Please see my EDIT in the question.

Comment: There seems to be no way to get the information whether my TaskBar Icon is shown or hidden. Ho to get this information?

Comment: @user1580348 changing `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar` in the `OnCreate` event is too late, it needs to be set in the DPR before either window is created. And yes, there are side effects to messing with `ShowMainFormOnTaskbar`, lots of VCL integration with the OS is tied to it, so I suggest leaving it set to True always for the best OS support.

Comment: Thanks again, Remy, for the mention of `DeleteTab` and `AddTab`. I now use this to control my TaskBar icon, and it works very well!